# How to handle [untagged] questions

Tags: discussion, tags

I took a look at all the [untagged](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged) questions

When selecting the retag option on a question the right-hand side help shows:
► favor existing popular tags; **avoid creating new tags**(emphasis mine)

Now I'm wondering: May I go on a re-tagging spree and create tags for games (some with only 1 question) or do we have a policy regarding this?

Comment: The problem is the auto-removal of single-use tags after six months, which is harmful on this site. [The correct solution would be to disable the auto-removal of tags](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/5379/stop-removing-tags-that-are-only-used-once-in-the-last-6-months), anything else just delays the problem by 6 months.

Comment: What's most frustrating is that some of those have *no indication whatsoever* what game they're about. :(

Comment: @RilgonArcsinh most of them have some indication, and with some of them the past edits hold's some clues.

Comment: @Josefvz Oh, sure, some of them are pretty obvious, but there are ones that are just completely inexplicable. What game is, for example, [this?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/61484/what-is-the-formula-for-bonus-experience-from-armsmaster)

Comment: @RilgonArcsinh I do understand, fortunately i have mad Google skills. http://bit.ly/SYJugy 4th link

Comment: @Josefvz please don't post LMGTFY links. They are not allowed for good reason, which is mostly that it's the most condescending way to point anything out.

Comment: @murgatroid99 Sorry about that, did not mean to seem condescending. It's a bad habit i have.

Comment: It's OK, as long as you don't do it again. The problem I had was that the links are actually blacklisted, which means that your shortened URL makes it look like you saw that you could not post LMGTFY and then purposely circumvented the ban.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please do go ahead and retag these questions (slowly) if you feel like it. The pruner only acts on tags that are six months old, so should it (hopefully) get turned off in the next six months we'll already have those questions fixed.

Comment: Going slowly is unfortunately not part of my skill-set...

Comment: Now i understand why i should go slowly... you could have told me i'll be bumping them to the front page....

Comment: @Josefvz oh yeah, you'll bump everything you edit to the front page! Just thought you should know! :P